# beforeinstallprompt only firing if serviceworker not yet installed

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have the following code that only fires if serviceworker is not yet installed, if I reload the page, it no longer fires, I did not add the code yet to install the PWA (deferredprompt does nothing).  I'm using Chrome.  I am not declining the prompt, I am not even displaying the prompt at the moment.

```
let deferredPrompt = null;
    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
        // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
        e.preventDefault();

        consolelog('=== before install prompt fired ===', 3)
        // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
        deferredPrompt = e as any;



    });
```

Comment: Which browser & OS? Are you declining the first prompt (if seen)?

Comment: Chrome.  I am not declining the prompt

Comment: Desktop or Android?

Comment: Desktop........

Comment: Seems to work Ok for me Chrome 73 on Mac. Here is my tester.https://a2hs.glitch.me/  Do you have a URL you can share for others to test?

Comment: I was wiring up my event too late... like inside of a system.js import and I missed the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event fires immediately on load (if you have a serviceworker installed), and I was wiring up the event too late, so I missed it.

Comment: hey I have a similar issue can you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55797611/tying-to-update-pwa-swupdate-isenabled-is-true-but-not-calling-the-subscribed-m